# Rails index of an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I find myself requiring this.  Assuming cart is a model which has a list of users.

```
def index_of_item
 cart.users.each_with_index do |u, i|
  if u == current_user
   return i
 end
end
```

What's an easier way to get the index of an association like this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [index](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002178) method on `Array` does the same as your `index_of_item` method e.g.

```
cart.users.index(current_user)
```

Returns the index of the first object in the array that is == to obj. Returns `nil` if no match is found.

Comment: I used find_index, but it looks like these do the same thing.  Thanks!

Comment: Yep, it looks like as of 1.8.7 find_index has been added to Enumerable and Array#index is now just an alias to that.